# Using Map Fragment from another class

Tags: android, fragment

I want to use the map fragment from another class, called MapsActivity.

EDIT: Ill try to explain better, the goal here is to use the Fragment generated from the class MapActivity to load my position. However, Im using my main class which already has one Fragment. So I guess I must link the Fragment on my main class with the MapActivity fragment. If you suggest to use the same class to do that, thats ok for me i just don't know how to load my position on a map fragment with my custom class instead of this MapActivity class i got here.

On my main class i got just this, which will be the view that i want:

```
private MapFragment mapFragment;
```

on my main class .xml i got this:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapCheckinFazerActivityMapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgCheckinFazerActivityBG"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtCheckinFazerActivityTitle"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

now, i got the MapsActivity class, which is the basic one after I've making some researches...

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapCheckinFazerActivityMapView);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        Log.d("MYTAG", "READY");
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    public void test(){
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

also i got MapsActivity .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewController.MapsActivity" />
```

it does work if i use this class MapsActivity directly, but i want just to use it as an object on my main activity. Can u please give me some help? thanks in advance...

EDIT:

Maybe with this image it could be better to explain. On my MainActivity i got this map which (by what i could do) I want to be Google map of MapActivity class... as u can see the map is not recognized and function OnMapReady is not called

[image]

Comment: Not really sure what it is that you're trying to accomplish and looking at the amount of attention this question has gotten, I'm guessing I'm not the only one not understanding your question. Could you try to rephrase it or add more info about your problem perhaps?

Comment: @Darwind sorry for my bad explanation... I agree with you. Ive just edited, let me know if you can understand now what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you want to access your **GoogleMap** object from MainActivity.java class. Here is how can you do it using **Interface** :

First of all, you can create interface, like this, you can add this code, in your **MainActivity.java**

```
public interface MyMapInterface {
    void onMap(LatLng ltlng);
}
```

Then, declare, **myMapInterface** in your **MainActivity.java**, as

```
private MyMapInterface myMapInterface ;
```

One more thing to do in your **MainActivity.java** is use call the method of the interface, wherever you want to access the **GoogleMap** object:

```
myMapInterface.onMap(sydney);
```

Now, come to your **MapActivity.java** class, and make your Activity implement the interface, like this :

```
MapActivity implements MyMapInterface
```

when you do so, you will see red line below that line, click Alt+enter and it will prompt you to add the method **onMap(Latlng ltlng)**, add that method by clicking on enter key, then you can access your map like this :

```
@Override
    public void onMap(Latlng sydney) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in 
        Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
```

**Edit**

Sorry for the inconvenience caused, please try this :

make your interface extend **Serializable** class

```
public interface MyMapInterface extends Serializable {
    void onMap(LatLng ltlng);
}
```

then, pass your interface object in intent **MapActivity.java** like this :

```
intent.putExtra("MyMapInterface", this);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in, **MainActivity.java** :

```
myMapInterface = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyMapInterface");
```

Comment: Dear MoFaizanShaikh seems like u are in the right way to go and understood my question. Ive did all these 4 steps but myMapInterface is still null so i got crashed. Then I've decided to instantiate it with this but got nothing on response from the app...

myMapInterface = new MyMapInterface() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMap(LatLng ltlng) {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                        myMapInterface.onMap(latLng);
                    }
                };

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience and the late reply, please check the edit

Comment: thats ok, no inconvenience at all.. if i got this new idea right seems like u are starting one activity in MapActivity which is not what i expected. The idea here is having a Map on MainAcitivity view which is an instance of MapAcitivity class, in any moment i am starting new activities...

Comment: Ive just edited the question, maybe now is more clear

Comment: No, I am not telling you to start a new activity, but I want you to pass the object of MyMapInterface from MapActivity.java in the intent you already are calling to start MainActivity.java, hope you understand, if you don't then tell me

Comment: check my edit, pass this in intent, which will pass your implemented interface in MapActivity

Comment: much thanks for your help Mo! Ive saw that if i do this on my Main Class "implements OnMapReadyCallback" and implement the method it works perfectly

Comment: Yeah, that's more simple, Can you accept my answer and/or upvote the answer if it was helpful? Thanks :)